# bootstrap dropdown menu sets display:none when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu in bootstrap. When I click my element it shows the dropdown and when I click  away it collapses the dropdown menu. However, when I click away the element also disapers, I checked, and it gets display:none set. Why is this happening?

This is my list

```
<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
<li class="" id="current">
    <a class="" href=""> Nyheter</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="" href="">test</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="" href="">Schema</a>
</li>
<li class=" dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/info">Info </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="">
            <a class="" href="/info/checklista">Checklista</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="" href="/info/laenkar"> Länkar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="" href="asd"> test2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="" href="/bilder"> Bilder </a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="" href="/kontakt"> Kontakt </a>
</li>
```

Comment: please put jquery code also u tried

Comment: Its standard bootstrap. I dont use any extra jquery code.

Comment: When I click info, the dropdown appears. When I click away, the dropdown but the Info button does not disappear. Proof: http://www.bootply.com/xXSuRzso46 Will you clarify?

Comment: I can see that it works there. But on my site the "info" button disappears when the menu collapses.

Comment: solved it! Was a joomla thing :)

Comment: @AlexanderNajafi how did you solve this? I'm using Joomla and it's doing the same for me

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5L37/)**

```
<nav id='myNavbar' class='navbar navbar-default' role='navigation'>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped -->
    <div class='container'>

    <!-- you are missing this part below -->

        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'> 
                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>

            </button> <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Menu</a>

        </div>


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>
            <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="" id="current"> <a class="" href=""> Nyheter</a>

                </li>
                <li class=""> <a class="" href="">test</a>

                </li>
                <li class=""> <a class="" href="">Schema</a>

                </li>
                <li class=" dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/info">Info </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class=""> <a class="" href="/info/checklista">Checklista</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class=""> <a class="" href="/info/laenkar"> Länkar</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class=""> <a class="" href="asd"> test2</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""> <a class="" href="/bilder"> Bilder </a> 
                </li>
                <li class=""> <a class="" href="/kontakt"> Kontakt </a> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```